# idangerous swiper partually locks on swipe

Tags: jquery

I would like to find a way to make idangerous swiper to act more smoothly. It does not.

Looking at their homepage, here is an example.

http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/demos/main-demos/17-responsive.html

It does not start directly with swipe. Can I configure this?
Its a bit of glitch after release, the freemode fluid does not act this way,
but do not stop on each swipe "area".

Tested on Chrome.
Thanks!